# Add minType on specific folder?

Tags: lighttpd

I installed lighttpd-1.4.28 to serve static files,but I want to add mintype (html) on specific folder not all document root how, can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mintype but lighttpd's conditional config file stuff is quite powerful. Take a look at this URL under "Conditional Configuration" : http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:Configuration

Specifically, you can make a config block apply only to a certain URL regex.

Their example:

```
# disable directory-listings for /download/*
dir-listing.activate = "enable" 
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/download/" {
    dir-listing.activate = "disable" 
 }
```

In your case you could try

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "REGEX MATCHING SPECIFIC FOLDER" {
    # mintype settings you want for folder go here
}
```